# Is $R^4\setminus S^3$, with the subspace topology on $R^4$, connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$S^3=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1\}$

Is $R^4\setminus S^3$, with the subspace topology on $R^4$, connected?

Comment: I'd start by thinking about $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^2$ since these cases are easier to visualize.

Comment: @carmichael561 Consider $B(0, 1)$, the open ball in the euclidean metric. Would $R^4\setminus S^3-B(0, 1)$ be open. If so, these 2 sets could form a separation of $\mathbb R^4\setminus S^3$.

Comment: You see there are two components of that set ($x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2\ne 1$), a bounded one with $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2<1$ and an unbounded one with $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2>1$.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you have the right idea.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:  the set $[0,1) \cup (1,\infty)$ in $\mathbb R$ is not connected, but it is a continuous image of your set.

Answer (score 0):

You have the idea in the comment you posted. The two sets $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \::\: |x| < 1\}$ and $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \::\: |x| > 1\}$ are clearly disjoint and their union is $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus S^3$. If you prove these facts, you've shown that $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus S^3$ is indeed disconnected.

Comment: I don't know how to prove that the 2nd set is open.

Comment: @Thomas You must prove that it is open _as a subset_ of the space $R^4 \setminus S^3$.

Comment: Pick an arbitrary point in that set, and find a ball around it that is still contained in the set. Note that the region is unbounded so I only need to make sure the chosen ball doesn't intersect $B_{(0,0)} (1)$.

Comment: @Thomas Inverse images of open sets by continuous maps are open. The second set is $f^{-1}(\{x:x>1\})$, where $f:\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R$ is given by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1^2+\dots+x_4^2$.

Answer (score 0):

A picture is worth 996 words:

[image]

As for the other four words you will be needing:

The Reverse Triangle Inequality

---

So the outside of the unit sphere is open and the open ball about the origin is open.

Voilà - you gotta disjoint union of two open sets!